# Blueish Screen and blue stripes

Tags: screen, touchscreen, motorola-moto-g, motorola

My phone has a blueish layer over everything, differing from app to app, also blue stripes. When I make a screenshot it doesn't show on the screenshot. It's a Motorola Moto G 1st gen

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue, not software. Hence the clean screenshot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing a reset with no result I contacted Motorola, they are going to replace the screen.